Host Node JS and database application in the same Digital Ocean droplet
I am kind of a beginner working with digital ocean and database management. I am planning to rent a Digital Ocean droplet when I am going to host my Node js application. I see that Digital Ocean also offers cloud database services. I plan to rent a 1 GiB 1 vCPU digital ocean droplet that has a value of $6/m, and the cheapest database plan for any database (Mongo, Mysql, Postgres) is 1 GiB 1 vCPU for $15/m. My questions is the following
¿Can I pay a higher droplet machine like 2 GiB 1 vCPU for $12/m in order to increment the resources and host both the Node js app and any database saving some money, or it's better to have these things in different servers?
Some extra information:

I know that there are many free tier database options, like Mongo Atlas, AWS RDS or Azure, but these options only are available for 1 year and I want to have some more dedicated and flexible option from the beginning. I see the pricing outside the free tier in these platforms and I found they are greater than digital ocean options but this is because they have more resources, however, I want to start with a cheaper plan.

Some extra questions:

If the monthly price of the droplet is not a problem, ¿Is the approach of host Node application in a Digital Ocean droplet better than some serverless services like Cloud Functions or Lambda Functions in terms of speed, efficiency, and scalability?
¿There is any difference between deploying the Node JS application in the droplet through the GitHub account in the Digital Ocean panel than installing node js and configuring nginx and other stuffs manually?

I would appreciate any information you can give me in order to understand better what things I have to take in account and how to start in these topics, and if you know about different approaches, options, cloud databases services or any opinions i will be glad to hear you, I am a beginner in these topics and It's easy to get lost with so many options available today, so any extra information or advise it will be great. Thanks a lot and sorry for so many questions.
